# regex pattern to allow alphanumeric and special char(,-\s) with size checking

Tags: regex, validation

i want to check for a string that only contains alphanumerics and few special chars which are:

1) dash 
2) space 
3) dot

with size 3-255 characters only.

but my below expression doesnt seems to work..something is wrong with the size i think..

`@Pattern(regexp = "^[-a-zA-Z\s\.]{3,255}+$"`

i even tried this:

`@Pattern(regexp = "^[-a-zA-Z\s\.]\w{2,256}+$"`

but that raises issue to the size validation due to the \w char - because it will only accepts alphanumeric and not special chars i guess...

any idea??

Comment: Always add the language to questions regarding regex. Your first regex is only missing the numeric characters, everything else should work in a lot languages (not in all). Do you want only ASCII letters or all letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dash is special key too. add backslash. And you don't need + to the end.

```
^[\-a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]{3,255}$
```

Comment: The dash is a special character in a character class, but at the start or end it does not need to be escaped (but it does not hurt)

Comment: @zomboid : thanks !! it works..and what stema said was correct.. i dont need the backslash if my dash char stays at the start or end of the tag..